# C# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: F(double)' and 'F(decimal)'

Tags: c#, double, decimal, ambiguous

This code works quite well in C# despite the fact that **int** can be implicitly converted to **double** and **float**:

```
void Main()
{
    int x = 7;
    F(x);
}
void F(double a)
{
    a.Dump("double");
}
void F(float a)
{
    a.Dump("float");
}
```

So, why this code won't compile? (The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'UserQuery.F(double)' and 'UserQuery.F(decimal)')

```
void Main()
{
    int x = 7;
    F(x);
}
void F(double a)
{
    a.Dump("double");
}
void F(decimal a)
{
    a.Dump("decimal");
}
```

All I did was replace the `float` variant of the function with a `decimal` variant.

Comment: What does the Dump function look like?

Comment: This is equivalent to Console.WriteLine("something").

Comment: can you update whole class ??

Comment: @jdweng Code is written in LinqPad

Comment: The decimal class has the following definition : public static explicit operator int(decimal value); while the float class doesn't.  So a decimal you have to have a cast to convert an integer to a decimal while float will automatically do the cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no implicit conversions between floating-point types and the decimal type.

If there's methods with float, double signatures there's no problem to determine a compatible method based on a minimum graduation requirements (the float method will be chosen).

There's no such rule when dealing with float-point types and decimal as there's no implicit priority between double and decimal and it must be specified explicitly.